# Git alias doesn't do the same thing as the aliased command

Tags: git, alias, msysgit, posh-git

I'm still relatively new to Git, so perhaps I'm doing something stupid, but I have a weird issue...

I defined a `stage` alias for `add --all`, because I find it shorter and more self-explanatory:

```
D:\MyProject [master +0 ~1 -1]> git config alias.stage "add --all"
D:\MyProject [master +0 ~1 -1]> git config alias.stage
add --all
```

But when I run `git stage .`, it behaves as if the `--all` option was omitted:

```
D:\MyProject [master +0 ~1 -1]> git stage .
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'MyProject.Tests/AssertExtensions.cs' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.

D:\MyProject [master +0 ~1 -0 | +0 ~0 -1]>
```

However, running `git add --all .` gives the expected result.

**What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?**

(I'm using [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) and [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) on Windows)

---

UPDATE: if I rename the alias to `stg`, it works fine!! I just realized that there *is* already a [`stage` command in Git](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stage.html), and it's a synonym for `add`... so I can't override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git already has a built-in `stage` command, and it's a synonym for `add`... And apparently it's not possible to override a built-in command with an alias. If I rename the alias to `stg`, it works fine.

Comment: You're correct that Git won't let you alias over an existing command. FWIW, Git 2.0 changes `add` behavior to be more like `add --all` pre-2.0 (stages removal of files), so your alias may no longer be necessary.

Comment: @dahlbyk, yes I know, but I'd like to have this behavior now ;)